# Would like to install QGIS web app builder

Tags: qgis, boundless-suite, boundless-web-app-builder

I would like to install QGIS web app builder plugin. I followed all the instructions in the website as closely as possible (installing Boundless desktop, etc etc.)

When I open QGIS for boundless desktop 1.1 as per [this website](http://boundlessgeo.github.io/qgis-plugins-documentation/webappbuilder/installation.html) and try to follow the steps I get the following error when switching to plugins tab in Boundless Connect pane:

> There has been a problem performing the search: Network error #503:
>   Error downloading
>   https://api.boundlessgeo.com/search/matchAll?version=0.1&cat=BLOG,DOC,QA,LESSON,LC&si=0&c=20
>   - server replied:

So instead I tried to install the web app builder using Plugins>Manage and Install Plugins. I did find it in my list of plugins but when I click on Install plugin I get the following error:

> Plugin installation failed:Error downloading
>   https://qgis.boundlessgeo.com/plugins/packages-auth/webappbuilder.1.0.zip
>   - server replied: FORBIDDEN

There is no material online which indicates why this problem is happening. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Simply look at [GitHub:boundlessgeo/qgis-webappbuilder-plugin](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/qgis-webappbuilder-plugin/releases)

> To install, download the latest release from the [releases page](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/qgis-webappbuilder-plugin/releases) and unzip it in the QGIS plugins folder at [your_user_folder]/.qgis2/python/plugins

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing. But that doesn't download the latest version ... I'm trying to carry out the following tutorial http://boundlessgeo.github.io/qgis-plugins-documentation/webappbuilder/tutorials/bakeries/index.html which requires the full screen web app type. What you get from the zip only has basic and tabbed as web app types...